# Repeated addition and comparisons of floating point numbers

Tags: python, number-formats

In the following program where I repeatedly *half* an integer, it takes until `i = 1074` for my integer to be equal to zero (I know that ideally the while loop shouldn't have ended, and the reason why it stopped was because of the memory limit of the computer).

```
a = 1.0
i = 0
while a != 0:
    a = a / 2
    i = i + 1
    print(a, i)
```

However, the next program, where I compare the *halved* integer using addition ends at `i = 53`.

```
a = 1.0
b = 1.0
i = 0
while a + b != b:
    a = a / 2
    i = i + 1
    print(a, i)
```

My question is *why is there a big difference* here?   Why does the first program go up to `1075` iterations, while the latter goes up to `53`?

Also, when I tried `a + b + c != b + c`, it went up to just `52`, furthermore

```
a + b + c + d != b + c + d
```

only went up to `51`.  Why isn't there a big difference here?

Comment: You have print statements already there. What do they print? Once you see what's printed it should be obvious. And of course this has nothing whatsoever to do with "memory limits". And of course you are _not_ doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing these results are not due to the memory limits of your computer, but rather of the limits of the encoding of "floating point" numbers.  Python uses 64 bit floats (aka double precision floating point numbers), which are well described on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

In short, there are only 52 bits for the significand and 11 bits for the exponent.  $2^{1023}$ is the highest exponent that can be represented.